# unable to run selenium chrome headless mode in Windows 7 enterprise

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, headless

I am trying to run selenium chrome headless mode in Windows7 enterprise edition. I have:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options() 
options.add_argument('--headless')
 options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
 options.add_argument('window-size = 1920,1080') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

I get:

```
chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed
```

The same set of commands works perfectly on my mac book pro
anyone knows why?

Comment: looks like issue is here `executable_path="chromedriver.exe"`

Comment: also can you share chrome driver version , and chrome browser version ?

Comment: My Chrome browser  = 91.0.4472.124

Comment: the chrome driver = 91.0.4472.101

Comment: they are up to date, so we can rule out driver mis-match issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try with full file path at this line :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/full file path/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```